# Meaning of the phrase 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間」

Tags: words, translation

I've been reading 魔法使いの夜 and stuck with this sentence -「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」. I completely cannot grasp the meaning from it, so I'll try to break it into parts and translate them.

「体幹の見切り」 - the weak(見切り) part of torso

「筋肉の凝固弛緩」 - solidification and relaxation of the muscles

「その隙間」 - their weak point(opening)

Can you please tell me where I'm mistaken, and help me with translating it. Thank you!

> 彼の思考には初めから、その点しか存在しない。ーー狙うは一点。意識の同一、呼吸の合致。体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。その地点こそ、唯一とも言える、生命の壁の亀裂である。人狼の胸に叩きつけられる、あまりにも弱い人の力。

Full scene: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU-27H4XNAc (This part starts at 1:23)

Comment: 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」 is NOT a sentence.

Comment: Well it *is* copied verbatim from the video, so the mystery deepens

Comment: @ssb I read the comment above as pointing out that it's a noun phrase rather than a complete sentence--there's no predicate.  (I edited the title to say "phrase" instead of "sentence".)

Comment: @TokyoNagoya I'd very much like it if you could weigh in on this phrase. "AとBその隙間" reads to me like "the gap between A and B" but B isn't a location here. Is this even well-written Japanese? Is it a coherent thought? What exactly is 見切り? (Dictionaries aren't helping -- I found 見切り線 but it appears to be a specialist term.) 
ken_a's answer is too airy for me, giving a sense of "appreciate the feel and pretend like you understand".

Comment: @Hyperworm As far as I can understand 見切り here is kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%8B%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A - 大辞林 3rd one. 
Also I would like learn more about "AとBその隙間 phrase too, so if it's fine, I'll leave the question open for now.

Comment: @snailboat That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Hyperworm I feel a little funny posting an answer when OP clearly seems satisfied with the existing one --- whatever problems it may contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To repeat what I stated in the comment,  「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間」 is NOT a sentence by any standard.   It is only a noun phrase in which everything else will eventually end up  modifying the last noun  隙間.  I repeated it because so many members here call little phrases "sentences".

隙間 is a key word here.  If one thinks of a "spatial gap" just because a dictionary says so, one will be left in the dark with the whole phrase.  The word is being used to refer to a "temporal gap" here.  I shall return to this point.

体幹の見切り might be a difficult phrase to comprehend because 見切り is being used as a technical martial art term here rather than for a usual dictionary meaning.   It means pulling back one's upper body to parry an attack.

筋肉の凝固弛緩 means what OP stated without a twist.

Now, in order to pull back one's upper body,  筋肉の凝固 naturally must occur, followed immediately by 筋肉の弛緩.  That split second between the two sets of muscle activities is what the author refers to as その隙間.  He is saying that that is the  ultimate moment for an effective attack because that is the only moment that the opponent is defenseless.

If it helps the Japanese-learner, try inserting a 「それに伴う」　between 「体幹の見切りと」and「筋肉の凝固弛緩」with それ referring to 体幹の見切り.  It MIGHT become a little easier to understand the phrase.

Comment: "That split second between the two sets of muscle activities is what the author refers to as その隙間." >Aaaahhhhh. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What difficult Japanese you are reading!

I think your understanding is correct. 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」is the point 彼 has been thinking to strike to defeat the enemy 人狼. 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」is not a full sentence, but a looong noun, more description of その点 introduced in the first sentence.

Perhaps 彼 has not found the exact point to strike yet. 彼 has to syncronize his mind with that of the enemy, has to syncronize his breathing with the enemy to completely capture the right place and the right moment. Even has to watch how enemy's body moves, how its muscle tightens and untightens. There must be opening in his body. That's the only place he strikes. 彼 well recognizes how weak people are before 人狼, so 彼 has been thinking to find out the right place to hit, he's been thinking only about it from the beginning and nothing else. If he misses, that means his immediate death.

This is my version of understanding when I read the paragraph, not verbatim translation (sorry!) Your translation of parts of 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」is correct, you are not mistaken.

Hope this helps you understand the paragraph!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I think I understand the meaning now.

Comment: @ken_a How could you say "Your translation of parts of 「体幹の見切りと筋肉の凝固弛緩その隙間。」is correct, you are not mistaken."???  OP syas "「体幹の見切り」 - the weak(見切り) part of torso" and "「その隙間」 - their weak point(opening)".  Are you calling those correct?  I DO NOT see where "weak" o "weak point" even comes from.  Frankly I do not see "weak" even once but you and OP see it twice in the phrase.